# Show values of boxplot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

How is possible to show the critical values of a box plot diagram in R?

75% line 25% line

```
o <- (ggplot(data=DFTvalues2, aes(Quarter, DFT)) +  
geom_jitter(aes(color=Quarter))+
geom_boxplot(alpha=0.7,outlier.color=NA))+
xlab("Pipe Quarter")+
ylab("Dry Film Thickness")+
ggtitle("DFT by Pipe Quarter")+
theme(
axis.title.x = element_text(color="Black",size=20),
axis.title.y = element_text(color="Black",size=20),
axis.text.x = element_text(color="Black",size=15),
axis.text.y = element_text(color="Black",size=15),
plot.title=element_text(size=20),
legend.title=element_text(size=15))
```

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear: what is `z`? What do you mean by "critical values"? Also, please include packages that you're using.

Comment: Those values  [link](http://prntscr.com/i877g0)

Comment: user3407156, I edited your question to add your commented image. In general, comments are easily ignored, so if you have something to add to the question (images, code, explanation), it often is better suited as an "edit" vice a "comment". (You should still address PoGibas's point of *"what is `z`"* and *"include packages"*.)

Comment: Thank you @user3407156 for the advices!I just edit the post followig your instructions

Comment: @EricFail . Not only the means but the lines that are appeard with red arrow in the screenshot

Comment: I see. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @EricFail I made only the above code. I don't know how to appear the values. I just started learing

Comment: try running some of the [geom_text examples](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_text.html) and take a look around SO to find related answer. Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17033521/1305688) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008863/how-to-draw-a-nice-arrow-in-ggplot2).  It's generally good to demonstrate you already put some effort into it. I will also recommend to take a look at the [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).