# annotate hline in ggplot with arrow

Tags: r, ggplot2

I make a boxplot like this, where I annotate the hline with "test"

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100))

ggplot(df, aes(y=x)) + geom_boxplot() + geom_hline(yintercept = 0.0) + 
   annotate("text", label = "test", x = 0, y = 0.2)
```

[image]

However, I actually want the "test" to appear at the bottom left corner and just add an arrow to the hline, like this

[image]

the arrow may be a straight line or bent.
This should be stable when I use it in facets with different y axis ranges, but the hline is always at yintercept=0

Comment: Does  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032393/how-to-draw-arrow-in-ggplot2-with-annotation) answer you question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(wrapr)

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100))

df %.>%
  ggplot(data = ., aes(y = x)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.0) +
  geom_text(aes(
      x = -.3,
      y = min(.$x),
      label = 'test'
    ),
    check_overlap = TRUE
  ) +
  geom_segment(aes(
      x = -.3,
      xend = -.2,
      y = min(.$x) * .95,
      yend = 0
    ),
    size = 1,
    arrow = arrow()
  )
```

If you want bent line use `geom_curve` instead of `geom_segment` and adjust curvature with `curvature` param.

Comment: what you suggest is basically defining the arrow by hand.

Comment: @spore234 Sry. I didn't read last line of yours question. See eddited answer.